# How to insert new rows into database from a submitted json string?

Tags: php, arrays, json, pdo, decode

I am not able decode and insert the array data in PHP. I tried to functions like `decode` and `foreach`, but nothing work.

The `$_POST['area']` data:

```
[area] => [{"text":"DATA1"},{"text":"DATA2"},*,{"text":"DATA3"}]
```

I am new to PHP, how can I insert these rows of data into my database with pdo's prepared statements?

```
$area = $_POST['area'];
foreach ($area as $data) {
    echo json_decode($data);
}

echo json_decode($area);
```

However it does not echo.

Ultimately, I want to use the data in this:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare(INSERT INTO `table` (`areas`) VALUES(:data));
$stmt->execute(array($data));
```

Comment: You need to decode the data first - `foreach (json_decode($area,true) as $data) {`

Comment: You need to `json_decode($area, true)` *before* you try to iterate over it

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you have an invalid json string because of the `*,`.

```
$_POST['area'] = '[{"text":"DATA1"},{"text":"DATA2"},*,{"text":"DATA3"}]';
//                        uh oh, not valid json -----^^
```

So I'll assume that this is a posting error and run with the following input data:

```
$_POST['area'] = '[{"text":"DATA1"},{"text":"DATA2"},{"text":"DATA3"}]';
```

This means that before you can iterate `$_POST['area']`, you must `json_decode()` it. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BMruV))

An unchanging prepared statement should be declared **before entering the loop** -- it is designed to be used over and over.

The binding of values to placeholders and the execution of the query is to be done **inside** the loop.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare(INSERT INTO `table` (`areas`) VALUES(?));
foreach (json_decode($_POST['area']) as $obj) {
    $stmt->execute([$obj->text]);
}
```

Comment: you didn't mention his incorrect json_format.

Comment: Posters often "yatta-yatta" their sample input.  The question itself remains clear regardless of this inaccuracy. I am overlooking this json invalidating substring so that a resolution can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your json format is incorrect. To do `json_decode();` you need correct json format

```
$post['area'] = [{"text":"DATA1"},{"text":"DATA2"},*,{"text":"DATA3"}];
```

changed it to

```
$post['area'] = [{"text":"DATA1"},{"text":"DATA2"},{"text":"DATA3"}];
```

then do

```
$ex = json_decode($data, true);
```

Comment: If the only trouble with the code is to remove the invalidating characters from the input, then you may attempt to close the question with something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/40054253/2943403  That said your recommended `$post` declaration is not valid php

Answer (score -1):

Use This:

```
$area = json_decode($_POST['area'],true);
```

You can't echo an array in PHP. You have to use the `var_dump()` function to do that.
Have a good day ;).

Comment: but how we can add in db insert function

Comment: if you want to save JSON in DB . you have 2 option. optioon1 if you want to query on values in area json you have to set area field type json and and json_encode it before pass it to insert . option2 you just want to save it and doesnt want to query on it you can just set text field type for area .

Comment: [area] => [{"text":"DATA1"},{"text":"DATA2"},*,{"text":"DATA3"}]
this is in incorrent json format, thats why it's not be decode.